# Return matrix instead of vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to do matrix calculation on slices of a matrix as `m1[, indice] %*% v1` where `m1` is a matrix with appropriate dimensions, `v1` is a vector with appropriate dimensions, and `indice` is the column indice of the matrix I want to slice.

But if `indice` contain only one integer, `m1[, indice]` will return a vector instead of a 1-column matrix, and the code will return an error.

I can definitely use `as.matrix()` to reformulate it. But is there a smart way to always automatically return matrix? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some reproducible data?

Comment: Use `drop=FALSE`, as in `m1[, indice, drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: See [`?[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) and its `drop=` argument. For instance, if `m=matrix(1:4,nr=2)`, then contrast `m[,1]` with `m[,1,drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: The `drop` argument works, thanks! Btw how did you look up the help file for `[]`? I tried `?[` and `?[]` but it only returns an error

Comment: For symbols and reserved words you need to back quote `?\`[\`` or use `help("[")`.